# SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces always returning ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS when trying to access usb data(control and interrupt pipes)

Tags: visual-studio, bluetooth, usb, wdk

I'm trying to access a USB data from a bluetooth device by using Visual studio 2013 and WDK. I created a WIN USB application in Visual studio and changed the DEVICE class GUID to Bluetooth GUID {e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974} in inf and device.h files. Now I need to access the USB control, interrupt and data pipes, but when I call SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces  I always get ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the sample INF appears to be missing the following sections in WDK 8.1

[USB_Install.Wdf]
KmdfService=WINUSB, WinUsb_Install

[WinUsb_Install]
KmdfLibraryVersion=1.11

After adding this to my INF, it installs OK

Make sure to generate a GUID from Visual studio and adding it in the registry, inf and device header file.